# What kind of shader to use for a particle simulation in openGL?

Tags: opengl, shader

I'm looking into creating a particle effect for when a ball collides with a dusty surface. My goal is to try and do as much on the gpu as possible.
To begin with I am going to be using some very basic physics, and then later on maybe explore fluid dynamics etc.

I am using instancing in openGL to draw but my knowledge of shaders is limited.

Originally I wanted to use CUDA but I assume that using openGL's own shaders would be better, because it allows direct access to the buffer objects.

My main question is, would it be best to use a compute shader or can it be done on the frag, vert, geometry shaders? like I have seen others implement?

Comment: You can use the CUDA - OpenGL interop to compute in CUDA and visualize in OpenGL, see for example http://3dgep.com/opengl-interoperability-with-cuda/. There are even some CUDA samples which render particles in OpenGL in <cuda-install-dir>/samples/5_Simulations/

Comment: Awesome, I never realised that this a was a possibility. Thankyou